# Swipe smoothness differ between divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swipe

I am using [react-swipeable-views](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views) in my project to enable touch swipe events. I can swipe between different `div`, which are inside `<SwipeableViews/>`. I have three different divs, out of which, in the 1st div, I have list of images. In the other two remaining divs, there's nothing.

```
export default class Photos extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const styles = {
          slide: {
            padding: '15px',
            minHeight: '500px',
            color: '#fff',
          },
          slide1: {
            background: '#FEA900',
            overflowY: 'hidden'
          },
          slide2: {
            background: '#B3DC4A',
          },
          slide3: {
            background: '#6AC0FF',
          }
        }

        return(
            <div id="profile_photos">

               <div id="profile_photos_nav">
                   <span class="photo_nav" id="photo_timeline">
                       <button class="active_btn">Timeline Photos</button>
                    </span>
                   <span class="photo_nav" id="photo_profile">
                       <button>Profile Photos</button>
                   </span>
                   <span class="clear_both"></span>
               </div>

               <SwipeableViews>
                    <div style={Object.assign({}, styles.slide, styles.slide1)}>
                        <img src="img/img3.jpg"/>
                        <img src="img/img5.jpg"/>
                        <img src="img/img6.jpg"/>
                        <img src="img/img7.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <div style={Object.assign({}, styles.slide, styles.slide2)}>
                        slide n°2
                    </div>
                    <div style={Object.assign({}, styles.slide, styles.slide3)}>
                      slide n°3
                    </div>
                </SwipeableViews>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, swiping between `slide2` and `slide3` is very smooth. But when swiping between `slide1` and `slide2`, its a bit jerky and not smooth. And when I check in the chrome console, I am getting this error:

> Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.
>
> :3000/#/profile/photos?_k=4qkf5g:1

If I remove the images form the 1st div, its working very smoothly again. What can I do to smooth out the swiping (while having the images in the 1st div) between 1st div and 2nd div? Please help me.

Comment: Try to load images of slide1 using timer once the swiping complete

Comment: One thing you could think about looking into is react-canvas. Flipboard has done some great stuff with this exact thing on mobile sites using canvas to make it feel very smooth.

Comment: Hi, I've thrown together a [WebpackBin demo](http://www.webpackbin.com/4kjOGHr2Z) with your code, please check it out.  It all looks silk-smooth on my (quad-core) laptop.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle and codepan link? to see what actualy does.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth trying the css property 'will-change' to tell the browser that the elements are likely to move.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/

Answer (score 0):

If it has something to do with the rendering engine, you could trigger the GPU, which is faster than CPU, applying some sort of css transformation (e.g. `rotate(0.00001deg)`) before the slide start sliding, and then remove the transformation at swipe done.

By the way, I don't know if this will raise a lot your slider performance, but it's worth trying.